# amp-list throwing error 400

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

Trying to implement amp-list, it works fine with the sample json file, but throwing me error 400 when I try to fetch data from a upstream api which is HTTPS and CORS enabled

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="100" layout="fixed-height" src="URL"> <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-id"> <div><a href="{{hosted_url}}">{{title}}</a></div> </template> </amp-list>
```